# Resolve nested GraphQL queries that don't match DB schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

*TLDR: How does one resolve nested GraphQL queries where the GQL Schema departs from the data stored inside of a MongoDB database?*

We've got an application where each user in our DB has array of foreign keys that reference other documents, in this case "pets." These pets are in a separate collection.

```
{
  "humans": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "bob",
      "pets": [
        "jBWMVGjm50l5LGwepDoty1",
        "jBWMVGjm50l5LGwepDoty12"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've got a GraphQL API in front of this DB and I'm trying to write my resolvers to handle nested queries. The problem is that our GraphQL schema does not match the DB schema. Inside of the `Human` type, the `pets` field expects an array of pets, like this:

```
  type Human {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    pets: [Pet!] # This is an array of pet objects...
    gender: String!
    hair: String!
    favoriteNum: Int!
    alive: Boolean!
    createdAt: Int!
  }
```

Currently, the humans resolver will query for a human by his/her ID, and return that human, like so:

```
human(parent, { input }, { models }) {
   return models.Human.findOne({ id: input.id });
}
```

The issue here, obviously, is that the returned human from the DB does not conform to the GQL schema. The array of "pets" is not an array of objects, it's an array of IDs. What is the proper way of resolving a query like this?

We've tried adding another DB call for the human's pets *inside* of the humans resolver. The problem here is that if someone makes a query for just the human's name, our resolver would have to go and fetch all of the pets data, even though our user did not request it...

The same problem would crop up again, however, if our pets had foreign keys! How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a design question. Graphql should always resolve a graph, so your query caller can be sure to receive all reference to this object. Let's take your human type and look at it as caller. When the caller sees there are `pets` in the human object he thinks he receives this object by doing a query like

```
query(
  human(id) {
    pets {
       stuffOnlyPetshave
    }
  }
)
```

So one approach is to query the pets from your database in the human resolver. That should be default way to get the complete graph.

But if you want to avoid the database query on every human query, then you should do a conditional pet query in you frontend.